# UPDATE using DBI in R

Tags: r, database, shiny, r-dbi

I have a data frame that I need to update using R DBI:

```
c= conn()
dummy <- reactiveValues(dummy_react = DBI::dbGetQuery(c, 'select * from dbname.dummy_df'))

observe({
    dummy_df <- reactive({dummy$dummy_react})
    
    newSupplier = "New Supplier"

    dummy_update_query = paste0("UPDATE dbname.dummy_df SET supplier='",newSupplier,"' WHERE dummy_Id=='",8,"'")

    DBI::dbExecute(c, dummy_update_query)
    DBI::dbClearResult(dummy_update_query)
})
```

| dummy_id | supplier |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | Supplier-A |
| 8 | Supplier-B (update this as New Supplier) |
| 201 | Supplier-A |

What am I missing here?
I am getting this error:
`Error in : external pointer is not valid`
I have updated my DBI package.

Comment: `dbExecute` calls `dbClearResult` internally, no need to call it separately - see `?dbExecute` - you should delete that line. If this doesn't help can you please provide a reproducible example using sqlite?

Comment: (1) `dbClearResult` is not something you execute on a string, it is on the result of `dbSendStatement` or similar. As ismirsehregal said, though, just call `dbExecute` and don't worry about clearing the result. (2) Don't `paste` queries together, it enabled accidental SQL injection and is prone to many problems. Use [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries), always. (3) SQL does not use `==` for equality, it uses just `=`.

Comment: (4) `external pointer is not valid` suggests that the connection was closed or failed. Reconnect and try again. (5) Don't use `"c"` as a connection object name; while legal, single-letter variables can be a bad idea to begin with, and using one that is a primitive function in R is at best confusing to humans, and it can be confusing to interprets depending on its use. Use something else, I often use `con` but choose something that is meaningful to you.

Comment: (Minor point, fyi: the [tag:rodbc] tag is for the [`RODBC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) package, which is not what you are using. The [tag:odbc] tag is a generic ODBC tag, and when coupled with the [tag:r] and possibly [tag:dbi] or [tag:r-dbi] tags, it typically indicates the [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) R package. Regardless, this question has nothing to do with that, just the SQL itself.)

Comment: Three *asides*: (1) it is really bad practice to name a local variable the same as a base R function (especially primitives, and double-especially something used *everywhere* such as `c`). While R generally can tell the difference, there are times when it will get it wrong, and this might be one of them. Name it `con` or keep it `conn()`. (2) I've never seen a situation like this where I needed `reactive({..})` *within an `observe` block*. I am not the shiny guru that many here are, so I might be missing something, but that seems wrong. (3) You never use `dummy_df`, so perhaps #2 is moot.